# How to get the value of Ajax response in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter

I am working with ajax and Codeigniter, I send a request by ajax to the controller and get a response like the below code:-

**Controller Response:-**

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#29 (1) {
    ["absent"]=>
    string(1) "4"
  }
}
```

the question is here that how can I get `4` from the response?

**ajax call:-**

```
 $('#staff').change(function(){
    let staff_id  = $(this).val();
    let month = $('#month').val();

    $.ajax({
        url:base_url+'hr/home/getStaffAbsentDay',
        type:'POST',
        data:{
            'staff_id':staff_id,
            'month':month
        },
        success:function(response){
            console.log(response);
            
        }
    })
});
```

**Controller:-**

```
public function getStaffAbsentDay(){
    $id =$this->input->post('staff_id');
    $month=$this->input->post('month');
    $this->stuff_model->get_staff_absent_days($id,$month);
}
```

**Model:-**

```
public function get_staff_absent_days($id,$month){
  $year =jDateTime::date('Y',false,false,true,'Asia/Kabul');
  $this->db->select('absent'); 
  $this->db->from('staff_attendance');   
  $this->db->where('staf_id', $id);
  $this->db->where('year', $year);
  $this->db->where('month', $month);
  $d=$this->db->get()->result();
  return json_encode($d);
}
```

Comment: `response` is an array with an object. Just use the regular ways to access the elements/properties of those data types.

Comment: So how can I do that?

Comment: Have a look at a tutorial on how to work with arrays/objects.

Comment: @Zia Yamin have your problem is solved or not?

Comment: @KUMAR no bro!  not solved

Comment: @Zia Yamin please see my updated answer.

Comment: @Zia Yamin please change in your model also , see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Model:-**

```
public function get_staff_absent_days($id,$month){
  $year =jDateTime::date('Y',false,false,true,'Asia/Kabul');
  $this->db->select('absent'); 
  $this->db->from('staff_attendance');   
  $this->db->where('staf_id', $id);
  $this->db->where('year', $year);
  $this->db->where('month', $month);
  $d=$this->db->get()->result();
  return $d;
}
```

**Controller function:-**

```
   public function getStaffAbsentDay(){
        
        $id =$this->input->post('staff_id');
        $month=$this->input->post('month');
   
   $your_array__data = $this->stuff_model->get_staff_absent_days($id,$month);
      echo json_encode($your_array__data);
   
}
```

**jQuery / Ajax Call :-**

and Now Your `response` will be a `JS array` instead of a `string` Format.

```
  success:function(response){
     var data = JSON.parse(response);
      console.log(data[0].absent)
      // $('#staffAbsentDays').html('success')
   }
```

Comment: this not worked bro! it says: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse

Comment: I used this  ``data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));`` and now it brings ``string(16) "[{"absent":"4"}]"``

Comment: I updated my question, please take a look, and also I tried your code and said the error in first comment

Comment: now the response is ``[{"absent":"4"}]``, so how can I get ``4``?

Comment: this ``console.log(data[1])`` return ``{`` for me

Comment: @Zia Yamin now check my ajax response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223688/discussion-between-kumar-and-zia-yamin).

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your PHP is using `var_dump` to output its data. This is a debugging tool for PHP. Don't use it to write APIs!

Output the data using a standard format instead:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo json_encode($your_data);
```

Then `response` will be a JS array instead of a string.